# HC-SR501 PIR sensor with 3.6V LED strip

Tags: transistors, mosfet, led, pir

I need your help with my HC-SR501. I'm not really deep into all the electronical device stuff, only got some basic knowlegde.
I did some research here but didn't find a solution to my problem.
I have a LED-strip powered by 3 AA batteries, 1.2V each. I'm using a build in LED strip and which can't be replaced. Using the HC-SR501 or 505, I want to get the LEDs turned on by motion. Only using the HC-SR501 works but the LEDs are super dimmed. So I googled a lot and found a Mosfet should help. But all youtube videos and posts here are only about 12V LED stripes. Thats where I start to struggle because I'm not deep enough to know which Mosfet to use now.
I built up my set up according to this [youtube video](https://www.youtube.com/watch?app=desktop&v=ugDPdgGekNo)/[Picture](https://i.ytimg.com/vi/ugDPdgGekNo/sddefault.jpg). But I used an IRLML5103 instead. Now the LEDs are shining brightly but they don't turn off. Can you help me explaining which mosfet to use?

Thanks!

Patrick

Comment: IRLML5103 is a P-channel MOSFET and cannot work in the suggested schematic.

Comment: Thanks! Which n channel Mosfet would you recommend for that low voltage?